# Perform action when div leaves screen (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am very new at `jQuery` and I want to dive right into it but i need help. I have provided a image below to explain what I need. What i want is when `#DivText` is scrolled up and no longer visible to the user I want to Animate `#ActionDiv`.

[image]

Please help me out with this I have been looking at `jQuery` plugins all day and so far none of them do what i want them to do.
The code I have so far ( requested )

```
<div class="welcomeimage" ></div>
<style>  .welcometext{
    color:white;
    font-size:50px;
    position:absolute;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-left: 150px;
    float:left;
    font-style:italic;
  }  </style>
```

I don't have any `jQuery` associated with it yet because I'm VERY new with `jQuery`.

Comment: show us what your code looks like so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you exactly want is jquery  `scroll()` event.
 there are many plugins available to achieve this 
 this is one of them
refere this link 
[ref](http://blog.webbb.be/trigger-css-animation-scroll/)
 and click on View the demo [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZVjWB)

If you want to know more basics about scroll() then refer this [link](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/)